# update application tile when the device is on battery, not connected to internet, 

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am trying to create an specific Calendar for Windows8 Metro User Interface.

All I want to do for now is to **update my tile at 12:00 am** (showing the current date on the tile) even **while the program is not running**.

WinRT provides multiple solutions for such task but I can not use any of them for various reasons:

1. It is possible to `Register a Maintenance Background Task` but they only run if the device is on AC power.
2. It is possible to `Register a Periodic Cloud URI` but they only run if the computer is connected to the internet.
3. It is possible to `Register a Background Task on Timer` but they only run if the user add them to lock screen.
4. It is possible to `Register a ScheduledTileNotification` but it's single, non-recurring scheduled update to a tile.

is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here is that you **have** to get added to the lock screen -- this isn't something that requires the user to dig into PC Settings. You can prompt to be added to the lock screen using the supported [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccessasync.aspx). Sample code is included in the Documentation -- it's a simple call, and a case of handling the result.

Comment: Only 7 apps can be on the Lock Screen. So, I think that it might not be the case since simple background tasks like this is so common.

Comment: No, that's the point. There aren't "global" background applications.  You really do need to be on the lock screen -- this allows the *user* to have control. If they don't put your app on the lock screen, then to *them* you app is not important enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be on the lock screen. Look into using scheduled tile notifications:

A code sample is here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scheduled-notifications-da477093

Comment: the problem with `ScheduledTileNotification` (used in your attached sample) is that it's a "MSDN: single, non-recurring scheduled update to a tile." this obviously is not working for my requirement.

Comment: For your situation, you could create more than one ScheduledTileNotification.  For example, each time your app is run, you could schedule out notifications for a year, creating one ScheduledTileNotification for each day.  (You'd obviously want to check to see if notifications have been previously scheduled so that you aren't duplicating effort.)

Comment: obviously, this is not the answer!